# How to modify each element of a parameter pack, and create a tuple from those?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, function-templates

I'm running into an issue with a variadic function template.  I need to examine each element of a parameter pack, package the element, then stuff all the packaged elements into a tuple and return that.  Here's the general idea of what I'd like to do (return types are just placeholders, not sure what they'd be):

```
template<typename A>
sometype func_helper(A a) {
    //examine a, depending on type, do different stuff with it.
    return modified_a;
}

template<typename... Args>
tuple<sometypes...> func(Args... args) {
    return make_tuple(func_helper...(args));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `return std::make_tuple(func_helper(args)...);`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was actually after with my question.  Can't believe I didn't try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use deduced return type. Sadly it has code reduplication:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename A>
int func_helper(A ) {
    //examine a, depending on type, do different stuff with it.
    return 1;
}

char func_helper(double) {
    return 'A';
}

template<typename ...Args>
auto func(Args... args) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(func_helper(args)...)) {
    return std::make_tuple(func_helper(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = func(1, 3.4);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(a) << ' ' << std::get<1>(a) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I didn't even realize I could call func_helper like that.  I knew I could deduce the type, but for some reason I thought sizeof() was the only function that could be called with the ... notation.  Anyway, just tried it, and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a form of auto return type that doesn't need the redundant decltype?

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice :)  Don't think that's available though.

Comment: @K-ballo: As if just to tease us, lambda functions have exactly that kind of deduced return type.

Comment: @pheedbaq: just to be clear, `sizeof...` is a specific identifier (non splittable), while `...` stuck to the right of an expression means: Take the pack within this expression and map the expression to each of its elements to produce a new pack. Therefore, `...` can be applied to arbitrary expressions containing an unexpanded pack.